# Type casting exception in trying to save html text box element using HTMLUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I've been trying to create a Java class to run a test against a website but I've hit a snag with trying to input a username and password into the site using the HTMLUnit API. The following is the html section I'm trying to base my code on:

> 

```
            <div class="inner_contain">

                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" border="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <form name="frm1" action="blank" onSubmit="defaultSubmit(); return false;" method="post">
                            <Td align="right"><strong>Username:</strong></Td>
                            <td><input type="text" maxlength="20" class="login_input" /></td>
                        </form>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <form name="frm2" action="blank" onSubmit="defaultSubmit(); return false;" method="post">
                            <Td align="right"><strong>Password:</strong></Td>
                            <td><input type="password" maxlength="20"
                                class="login_input" /></td>
                        </form>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="button" value="Login" class="submit" onclick="javascript:LoginSubmit('Login')" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
```

And the following is the code snippet to that section:

> final HtmlForm usernameForm = page.getElementByName("frm1");
>
> final HtmlTextInput usernameInput = (HtmlTextInput) usernameForm.getByXPath("//input[@class='login_input' and @type='text']");

But with or without the HtmlTextInput casting I still get an error of:

> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput

Any help in being able to submit a user's credentials would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to read [the API doc](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getByXPath%28java.lang.String%29):

> ```
> public List<?> getByXPath(String xpathExpr)
> ```
>
> Evaluates the specified XPath expression from this node, returning the matching elements

Note the return type, and the usage of the plural form. If you want to get a single element,then get the first element of the returned list, or use [`getFirstByXPath()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getFirstByXPath%28java.lang.String%29):

> ```
> public <X> X getFirstByXPath(String xpathExpr)
> ```
>
> Evaluates the specified XPath expression from this node, returning the first matching element, or null if no node matches the specified XPath expression.

Everything is much simpler when you read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks JB for the response. I've been digging into the documentation but I'm a little rusty with my Java so I'm trying to get back up to speed. I noticed the return type from the getByXPath(String xpathExpr) method is of type List. So I did the following to see the actual contents of what I was getting in return:

Comment: ArrayList test = (ArrayList) usernameForm.getByXPath("//input[@class='login_input' and @type='text']);

System.out.println(test.size());
System.out.println(test.get(0).toString());

Comment: And I get the following:

HtmlTextInput[<input type="text" maxlength="20" class="login_input">]

So I'm trying to see how I can then format this to be able to create and object of type HtmlTextInput

Comment: Don't cast the List to ArrayList. The method returns a List. Not necessarily an ArrayList. And you don't care: it's a List, and you can thus use the methods declared in the List interface. The first element is an HtmlTextInput, so use a cast:  `HtmlTextInput input = (HtmlTextInput) usernameForm.getByXPath("...").get(0);`. Or simpler: `HtmlTextInput input = usernameForm.getFirstByXPath("...");`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification with the additional examples! I'm getting past the typecasting error I was getting earlier. Thanks!